# How to properly store objects/pointers into a Qlist

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, object, qlist

I am new to Qt, and I came across this line:

```
    QList<Class*>* _lstChildren = new QList<Class*>();
```

where the class is derived from another class and has various constructors in it.

I am curious: why an extra `*` is used and what does `()` at the end means ?

Comment: Which `*` do you consider to be extra?  They all look to be correct to me.

Comment: The extra `*` indicates that it is a pointer to `QList<Class*>` object. The parenthesis at the end indicate that the default constructor of `QList<Class*>` should be called.

Comment: Note that there is no benefit in creating the `QList` with `new`, it is a container class that is implicitly shared and uses dynamic memory allocation internally.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing to do with Qt, it's pure C++ syntax

- `QList<Class*>` - type
- `QList<Class*>* _lstChildren` - variable, a pointer to aforementioned type
- `= new QList<Class*>()` - initialization of pointer variable by new-expression

`QList` is Qt analog of `std::deque`, `std::list` (not a direct equivalent of either), `Class*` is type to be stored passed as template parameter.

`()` here is part of new expression to initialize pointer with value that points at created object of `QList<Class*>` type.

It is calling default constructor in this case - no arguments provided inside parenthesis. If `QList` had no constructors at all, it would mean value initialization (by zeros) of created object.

Your list contains raw pointers, so you have to give it pointers to `Class*`, e.g. to create object in dynamic memory.

```
QList<Class*>* lstChildren = new QList<Class*>(); 

Class* child1= new Class();
lstChildren->append(child1);
```

It happens so `QList` should not delete objects pointed by those pointers, it would destroy only pointers themselves. To clean-up, you have to use

```
qDeleteAll(*lstChildren);
lstChildren->clear();
```

or delete them individually (and remove from list).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "extra" `*`.

```
QList<Class*>* _lstChildren = new QList<Class*>();
```

`_lstChildren` is a pointer `*` to a `QList`, which consists of pointers `*` to `Class`

And the `()` is at the end of `new QList<Class*>()` is there because the `QList<Class*>` object is initialized by [value initalization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Comment: () at end isn't really required in case of QList. It absense means that a default constructor would be called. It presence would mean value initialization if class have no user-defined constructors.

Comment: @Mike I tried to dissect the entirety of the `new QList<Class*>()` statement. I see that this was being confusing.

Answer (score 0):

1- If you put the extra '*', then _lstChildren will be a pointer to a QList that contains some pointers of class 'class'. You can remove it and then use _lstChildren as a normal variable.

2- The ending '()' is required. Why? because QList() is a constructor of a QList. You've seen it when creating a variable of your own classes.

3- As Qt company recommends, its better to use [QScopedPointer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscopedpointer.html) instead of raw pointers. This guarantees that the object pointed to will get deleted when the current scope disappears and you do not need to manage your object manually.